# Pyfirmata permission denied in Android (pydroid )

Tags: python, android, arduino-uno, usb-otg, pyfirmata

When I try to connect my Arduino uno with my Android device using pyfirmata (for connection) and kivymd(for ui) in pydroid ide , i get permission denied '/dev/bus/usb/001/002'.Im using usb otg connection.

Can someone help me let me connect my Arduino using pyfirmata in Android

Comment: Possible alternate approach: https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/issues/428